# Convergent series and its sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can anyone solve for the alternating sum of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{1+n^2} 
}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\ ...$$ I know that the sum is convergent by the leibniz test but i cannot seem to find it.

Comment: I doubt there is a known closed form...

Comment: I used Maple to numerically evaluate the sum (and got $0.4409\ldots.$)  I put that number into an inverse equation solver and got _no_ results.  The robot could find no algebraic or logarithmic expression involving $\pi$, $e$ and other constants which was even close to this number.  It surprised me, but it suggests that there's no nice, closed form for your sum.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)(s) = J_0(s)$ (a [Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html)) the given series equals
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{J_0(s)}{e^s+1}\,ds &=& \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n n!^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s^{2n}}{e^s+1}\,ds\\&=&\color{blue}{\log 2+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(-\frac{1}{16}\right)^n\binom{2n}{n} (4^n-1)\,\zeta(2n+1)}\\&=&\log 2+\frac{5\sqrt{2}-4\sqrt{5}}{10}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(-\frac{1}{16}\right)^n\binom{2n}{n} (4^n-1)\,\left(\zeta(2n+1)-1\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$
where the leftmost integral is simple to approximate numerically by exploiting $J_0(x)\approx \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ for $|x|\gg 1$ or
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{J_0(s)}{e^s+1}\,ds \approx \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{J_0(s)}{s+2}\,ds = \frac{\pi}{2}\left(H_0(2)-Y_0(2)\right) \approx 0.44.$$

Comment: This is quite open as a closed form... :)

Comment: And the downvote is for not providing a closed form to something that does not have a closed form? We cannot make pigs fly, guys, unless we carry them on a airplane.

Comment: this downvote is extreme nonsense (+1)

Comment: Hey Jack, have you considered applying Abel-Plana to your last integral? If this is possible, the remaining sums and integrals over Besselfunctions might be possible...

Comment: @tired: very interesting remark. How would you write $J_0(s)$ as $f(is)-f(-is)$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio yeah that is the crucial point...but anyway because the sum of interest is even more general then a Lerch-Transcendent  i don't think here is much to win here

Comment: maybe we can even proof that this is impossible? we know that $J_0(ix)=H_0(x)$ and $J_0(x)=J_0(-x)$ which should be enough

Comment: from the eveness of the 0-Bf it follows that $f(is)=f(-is)$ so we can't write down a  meaningful Abel-Plana formula in this case...Conclusion: Shitty idea from my side :D

Comment: @tired As an aside, a closed form may be found in terms of the Shintani zeta function, not that I'd find this especially helpful, but just worth the mention.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{1+n^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+i)^{1/2}(2n-i)^{1/2}}-\frac1{((2n+1)+i)^{1/2}((2n+1)-i)^{1/2}}$$

Thus, a closed form may be found in terms of the [Shintani zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shintani_zeta_function), not that I'd find this especially helpful.